# Passing Dates in Datasets across tiers

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, ado.net, dataset

I have a data set which I pass to a asmx-style web service. if I call the "GetXml" method on the ds, the content is displayed as the following string:

```
<ChinaVisa>
  <ChinaVisa>
    <ChinaVisaId>5</ChinaVisaId>
    <ReceiveDate>2010-11-07T23:00:14-05:00</ReceiveDate>
  </ChinaVisa>
</ChinaVisa>
```

I then pass this XML as a NTEXT parameter to a stored procedure. The stored procedure (simplified)  has the following code:

```
DECLARE @ChinaVisaHandle INT

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateOrder]
(
   @xmlChinaVisa NTEXT
)
AS

      EXEC sp_xml_PrepareDocument
         @ChinaVisaHandle OUTPUT,
         @xmlChinaVisa
      SELECT
         ChinaVisaId,
         ReceiveDate
      INTO   #TempChinaVisa
      FROM
         OPENXML (@ChinaVisaHandle, '/ChinaVisa/ChinaVisa', 2)
            WITH ( [ChinaVisaId]     INT,
                   ReceiveDate       DATETIME
                   )
```

I then use the data in the #TempChinaVisa table to write it to the actual master table.

```
  UPDATE [ChinaVisa]
  SET    
         ReceiveDate       = #TempChinaVisa.ReceiveDate
  FROM   #TempChinaVisa
  WHERE  #TempChinaVisa.ChinaVisaId = [ChinaVisa].ChinaVisaId
```

When I query the ChinaVisa table, the ReceiveDate is displayed to me adjusted by a 5 hour offset, essentially adjusting the timestamp to GMT. (I realize that the dataset contained this -5 GMT offset value.)

Result from querying the database target table:

```
SELECT ReceiveDate       FROM ChinaVisa

    OrderId ReceiveDate     
    5   2010-11-08 04:00:00
```

This surprised me a little. Since all of the application tiers were local, I at first, did not expect any conversion to another time zone. The date entered in the GUI, when converted to a dataset, included the local timezone offset of 5 hours. When I used Mgt Studio to display the date, I guess Mgt Studio had to decide whether the dates displayed were going to be in  local time or GMT. I would have expected everything to be converted to local, but since it displayed it as shown above, it appears as those Mgt Studio was displaying the timestamp in GMT time.

While a little surprising, it wasn't alarming. However, when my WinForm app used a web service to query the data, I expected that the  date, when accessed through he dataset, would automatically be adjusted to local time similar to the way that it was automatically converted when saving to the database, but it was not. When I moved the ReceiveDate to a DateTimePicker control,  the date displayed was "2010-11-08 04:00:00."

If i performed another save to take the date from the DatePicker control and save it to the database, this would have resulted in an unexpected  5 adjustment to the date. As a result, the value in the database would change by 5 hours each time the screen was refreshed from the database and re-saved, w/o changing the value on the screen.

What is the proper / easiest way to handle this situation? My gut reaction is to convert all datetimes read from teh database to local time before displaying, but I am not sure if this scenario would get more complicated if the database server or web service tier were running in different time zones.

Some advice?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the sanest way to handle dates across a distributed system is to store everything in UTC, and only convert to local time for user presentation as needed.  To my cursory eyes, your situation appears to be no different.  If you have the ability, I'd **strongly** recommend collecting/storing/retrieving **only** UTC datetimes.  To try to mix time-zone offsets manually is to invite madness and despair.